# azure Mobile app query like sql Statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I am working with Azure Mobile app and here is my SQL statement

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var query = {
            sql: "SELECT Id FROM Groups WHERE Members LIKE '%@userId%' and Members '%@friendId%' and type = @roomType ",
            parameters: [
                { name: 'userId', value: userId},
                { name: 'friendId', value: friendId },
                { name: 'roomType', value: type }
            ]
        };    

        context.data.execute(query)
            .then(function (results) {
                resolve(results);
            }).catch(error => { reject (error);});
    });
```

and I go to SQL and fill all variable like this

```
SELECT Id FROM Groups Where Members LIKE '%05adf56b-c128-4203-802f-d8d0e2916210%' and Members LIKE '%21B69402-7E9C-4BA3-99A8-6D84A96FA866%' and type = 0
```

and i got many records. so i didn't know what i did wrong

Comment: concat the wildcards: `LIKE '%' + @userId + '%'` (in both cases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your SQL statement looks incorrect, you may miss a `like` keyword for `Members '%@friendId%'`.

I have tested the following SQL statement on my azure mobile app, it returns nothing.

```
SELECT Id FROM Groups WHERE Members LIKE '%@userId%'
```

After some trials, I found the following statement could work as expected:

```
var query = {
   sql: "SELECT * FROM test5 where name LIKE @name",
   parameters: [
     {name:"name",value:"%"+req.query.param1+"%"}
   ]
};
```

> SELECT Id FROM Groups Where Members LIKE '%05adf56b-c128-4203-802f-d8d0e2916210%' and Members LIKE '%21B69402-7E9C-4BA3-99A8-6D84A96FA866%' and type = 0
>
> and i got many records. so i didn't know what i did wrong

Based on your description, it seems that your `Members` column contains many GUIDs. You need to check your table records by yourself, or you could update your question with more details about your records for us to narrow down this issue.